# Pandas interpolate until end of series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, interpolation

I have something like this:

```
DateTime             Col1     
2016-10-01 00:00:00  1.000
2016-10-01 01:00:00  2.000
2016-10-01 02:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 03:00:00  4.000
2016-10-01 04:00:00  5.000
2016-10-01 05:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 06:00:00  NaN
```

When I use `df.interpolate(method='time')`, the NaN values at the end are set to the same value as the latest before, meaning I get:

```
DateTime             Col1     
2016-10-01 00:00:00  1.000
2016-10-01 01:00:00  2.000
2016-10-01 02:00:00  3.000
2016-10-01 03:00:00  4.000
2016-10-01 04:00:00  5.000
2016-10-01 05:00:00  5.000
2016-10-01 06:00:00  5.000
```

What I actually want is for the interpolation to continue until the end:

```
DateTime             Col1     
2016-10-01 00:00:00  1.000
2016-10-01 01:00:00  2.000
2016-10-01 02:00:00  3.000
2016-10-01 03:00:00  4.000
2016-10-01 04:00:00  5.000
2016-10-01 05:00:00  6.000
2016-10-01 06:00:00  7.000
```

Is this possible without making my own interpolation function?

Answer (score 3):

You can't extrapolate data with `method='time'`.

You could use `method='spline'`:

```
df.interpolate(method='spline', order=1)
```

output:

```
                     Col1
DateTime                 
2016-10-01 00:00:00   1.0
2016-10-01 01:00:00   2.0
2016-10-01 02:00:00   3.0
2016-10-01 03:00:00   4.0
2016-10-01 04:00:00   5.0
2016-10-01 05:00:00   6.0
2016-10-01 06:00:00   7.0
```

Another approach if you want to combine two interpolation methods:

```
(df.interpolate(method='time', limit_area='inside')
   .fillna(df.interpolate(method='spline', order=1))
)
```

Comment: Thanks! The combination seems like a great solution.